# window.location break back button on browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When i click go , the b page is open. it is true. But when location changed i back the a.php its doesn't work. What is the my fail ?
I want to open a.php page when back button pressed how can i do it ? 
I tryed window.location.href , window.location.replace , window.location but i didn't successful. Please help me

**PAGE OF a.php**

```
$("#go").click(function(){
   window.location="b.php";
});
```

**PAGE OF b.php**

```
<html>
</html>
```

Comment: Are your files on the same directory?

Comment: yes the files same directory

Comment: So you can go from a to b but you cannot go back to a when you go back in your browser? can you expand your example please

Comment: Please send a jsfiddle because with a first test with location.href it works

Comment: why are you using jquery for this ? you can simply do in php

Comment: I cannot use php framework on my project its a hibernate